# how to get the text in shapes or picture in word document using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk, openxml

My word file containing list of paragraphs and images and shapes.Here, Some pictures(images) are grouped itself. And each group having one text box control with some text.The Shapes are also having the text i mentioned above.

Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs, i can able to get the paragraph text.But Could not able to get the those text.How can i get it.

In Open Xml representation, All text are inside the `<w:p>`.

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Saravanan.P

Comment: why not just use <w:p>.Value in Linq-to-XML? (Sorry, this is VB.NET as C# doesn't support literals, but it should be something similar with C#)

Answer (score 1):

You can use of "HasText" property  for this to work.

```
if (FileDocument.Shapes.Range(1).TextFrame.HasText != 0)
{
    Fieldstring.Add(FileDocument.Shapes.Range(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text.ToString());
}
```